# My table has lots of values in a column, however when I run a COUNT query lots of values are missing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

As my title says, I am trying to run a query using COUNT, however the results are not what I am expecting at all. I have run the following query:

```
    SELECT AdmissionReason FROM Episode
```

I have resulted in 70150 rows.
I have then run the following query and I get 0 results. This isn't possible as I know for a fact there are 1000's of rows with a NULL.

```
   SELECT COUNT(AdmissionReason) FROM Episode
   WHERE AdmissionReason IS NULL;
```

I was expecting this query to give me a count of all episodes where the AdmissionReason is null, however I am getting a result of 0.

Could I be missing something here?

Comment: You have no rows where `AdmissionReason` is `NULL`.  The query is working correctly.  Perhaps the value is an empty string `''` or the word `'NULL'`.

Comment: All [aggregate functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)(except `COUNT(*)`) ignore `NULL` values. `COUNT(expression)` will only count what is not `NULL` but you are selecting only null-values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`COUNT(SomeColumn)` doesn't count `NULL`. So `COUNT(NULL's) = 0`

try with

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Episode
WHERE AdmissionReason IS NULL;
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc2ad4/1)**

Comment: @GordonLinoff: why does [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) say that all aggregate function **except COUNT** ignore null-values. That's a bit confusing, isn't it?

Comment: I am pretty sure that they mean count(*) or count(1) will not ignore nulls.  It is confusing though.  They could say that count, in the right circumstance, is the only aggregate function that will not always ignore nulls?  ;)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for the help, will keep this in mind.